# How to "forced" maximize a window?

Tags: gnome, window, shortcuts, dialog, maximized

For some windows such as modal dialogs which is too small for long texts to display properly, "Maximize window"/"Super+Up" doesn't work but "Maximize window horizontally" and "Maximize window vertically" do.

Is there a way to chain the above two commands into one and bind the result to a key in GNOME?